# Yocto, export variable to host

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, yocto, bitbake

How can I communicate/pass values from a recipe to the OS environment. The jenkins-pipeline task which runs the bitbake has to know some values from the recipe.
I already tried export but the values didn't show up in the OS environment.

To be more specific, I want to know the `git` tag (description) that has been used to build in one of the recipes. In other words, the recipe in the meta-layer is checking out a certain git tag and this tag should be used as the build description for Jenkins.

Comment: I dont think you can do that directly, you might have to write scripts or something to grab the information. if you can run bitbake then it will be easier to use bitbake -e <recipe> and find the information you need in the output and process it.

Comment: You could try rephrasing the question: what info are you actually trying to deliver from the recipe to jenkins and why does bitbake need to export it?

Comment: @JussiKukkonen thank you for the hint, I added the rephrased question...

Comment: Just spitballing: can you include the tag in the package version number? Then you could parse the build artifacts (e.g. if this is an image build, grep the image package manifest for the specific package name to get the version) in the jenkins script...